# How do I convert a JSON string to a JS object and check the value of a property?

Tags: javascript, string, json

I have the following JSON-encoded object in a string:

```
{
  "loggedin": 0,
  "error_message": "login_failed",
  "success_message": "",
  "username": "",
  "sessionId": ""
}
```

How do I convert this to an object in JS, then check that its `loggedin` property is 0 or 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
var json = {"loggedin":0,"error_message":"login_failed","success_message":"","username":"","sessionId":""}

if(json.loggedin == 0) {
   // do something
}
else {
   // do something else
}
```

**Update:**

If you have the JSON as string, you have to parse it before you can do this. So maybe you have to do this:

```
var responseText = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

Comment: @udhaya: What is *responseText*? A variable? Then you can use it directly: `responseText.loggedin`.

Comment: alert(responseText);
shows this
{"loggedin":0,"error_message":"login_failed","success_message":"","username":"","sessionId":""}
so its a string?!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJSONObject = {"loggedin":0,"error_message":"login_failed","success_message":"","username":"","sessionId":""};
if (myJSONObject.loggedin === 0) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: alert(responseText); shows this {"loggedin":0,"error_message":"login_failed","success_message":"","username":"","sessionId":""} 

when alert(responseText.loggedin); it shows undefined.

Comment: That’s not a JSON object, it is a JavaScript object. JSON is a data format encoded as string and has to be parsed before you can check if a property exists.

Answer (score 0):

ha ha got it,
should use like this
var obj = $.evalJSON(responseText); 
alert(obj.error_message); //output:login_failed